# How I can delete an applet from my java card?

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I installed an applet on my javacard!  and now I want to delete it. How I can do it? 
I try "Reset Card" button in jcmanager and also `gpj -delete AID` but it not deleted! I also try gpshell but it don't work too. the output of gpj shown below:

**note: I download the .cap file from [here](http://wrankl.de/Javacard/packreadwrite.cap) [section:Java Card Applet for read and write data] and [here](http://wrankl.de/Javacard/ReadWriteJava.txt) is its source code.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to delete the executable load file without deleting the applet instance installed from it. Either change the parameter `P2` of the DELETE APDU to `0x80` (delete object and related object). GPJ does this if you pass the argument `-deletedeps`:

```
gpj -deletedeps -delete D2760000605002
```

Alternatively delete the applet instance (AID: `D2 76 00 00 60 41 02`) first.

Comment: thank you. but I've a question. I was uploaded a helloworld .cap file before and I delete it easily by `gpj -delete AID` . what's the difference between this .cap file and the helloworld .cap file?

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` command format looks ok

```
80E40000094F07D2760000605002

80E4000009
^^ ->  CLA 
  ^^ -> E4 :INS -> DELETE
    ^^ -> 00 : Reference Control Parameter P1 -> Last (or only) command
      ^^ -> 00 :P2 -> Delete object
        ^^ -> 09 :Lc -> Length of data field

4F07D2760000605002
^^ -> 4F: Tag-> Executable Load File or Application AID
  ^^ -> 07 : Length of Load File AID 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -> D2760000605002 :Load File AID
```

It looks `Load File AID` does not belong to applet which has been tried to delete.